# Variables in low power modes

Tags: c, stm32, sleep, standby

I am wondering what happens for variables & their content after STM32 mcu enters low power mode or exit from it? for example in sleep mode or standby.
do their content remove or survived?

best!

Comment: Low power modes woukd not be very useful if RAM contents got lost:)

Comment: Everything is described in the Reference Manual. Every model has different memory layout and you may set to keep some RAM areas or not.

Comment: @0___________ do you know of many microcontroller low-power states where the internal RAM loses data?  I have not seen any in my experience.  It is interesting that you use systems where reinitializing RAM is practical:)  That is not so much a low-power mode as 'switch it off and turn it on again'.

Comment: @MartinJames `do you know of many microcontroller low-power states where the internal RAM loses data?` yes, all STM32s if the programer decides that he wants to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preserve or not - it is usually (depending on the mode) up to the programmer. Memory consumes power so very often it is more energy efficient to reinitialize RAM after wake up (I do it sometimes in my projects)

Example: STM32L476:

[image]
[image]

Comment: So does that mean that SRAM *can* only be lost in Standby mode?

Comment: @WeatherVane no. You have control over it. if you disable the SRAMx clock it will switch off.

Comment: I see, note 3. So is the answer to the Q "Varaibles survive unless the programmer *specifically disables* SRAM"? Apart from Standby, where "disable" is the default.

Comment: Thanks a lot! is there any way to force compiler to use for example SRAM1 for storing a variable when I declare it?(By this way I want to turn on only one of two SRAMs).

Comment: @Amin-nano-sys, Of course, there is. Learn linker scripts.

Comment: @0___________, Would you leave a link or something like that for me to learn linker script for STM32L433 mcu?

Comment: @Amin-nano-sys google it - ld linker scripts. You have plenty resources. They are general, platform independent.

Comment: If you have a default CubeIDE project, look at the linker script file, it will be named something like "STM32F410RBTx_FLASH.ld". If you want something fast and easy, just declare only one RAM space = SRAM1, so the linker will use only SRAM1. You must know the location of this RAM, and its length. You can also, next step, customize your code and this file to put all functions and variables where you want, it's really powerful.